# How to convert XSD maxOccurs="unbounded", minOccurs="0" to OpenAPI?

Tags: xsd, openapi, servicestack-openapi

```xml
                        <xs:element name="EarningsData" minOccurs="0">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element type="xs:float" name="A"
                                        nillable="true" />
                                    <xs:element type="xs:float" name="B"
                                        nillable="true" />
                                </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
```

In the above XSD file, there are `minOccurs` and `nillable`. How can this be converted to OpenAPI?

Answer (score 1):

The `maxOccurs` and `minOccurs` indicate if it's an array element or not. The above XSD complex type definition is converted into the following OAS 3 model definition:

```yaml
    EarningsData:
      type: array
      minItems: 0
      items:
        type: object
        properties:
          A:
            type: integer
            format: float
            nullable: true
          B:
            type: integer
            format: float
            nullable: true
```

If the XSD has the `maxOccurs` attribute, it can be mapped to the `maxItems` property in OpenAPI. But if `maxOccurs="unbounded"`, it means there is no restriction on the number of elements, so you do not need to specify `maxItems` explicitly in OpenAPI.

Comment: If there  maxOccurs   is  unbounded like maxOccurs="unbounded"  then how we write it ?

Comment: According to the [spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-fge-json-schema-validation-00#section-5.3.2), an array instance is valid against "maxItems" if its size is less than, or equal to, the value of this keyword. Since with `unbounded` there is no restriction on the number of elements, you do not need to specify it explicitly in the swagger.